# What is a wise way to intuitively explain to a layman the concept of identifying a set with another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, education

If a student knows the concept of bijection, then it would be easier to pass to him the concept of identifying a set with another. That kind of "identification" concerning me is, for example, "We identify $A$ with $B$ if $A$ is homeomorphic to $B$.". But what is a wise way to achieve this intuitively? For instance, some authors intuitively explain the concept of continuity to a layman or a beginning mathematician by saying something like "A function is continuous if you can draw its graph in one stroke.". This example exemplifies what I mean by a wise way; it magnifies the main idea without losing too much precision. Another nice instance would be that of the concept of manifold; some authors introduce the idea of manifold to a general reader by saying something like "A manifold is a set that locally looks like a Euclidean space.". This "definition" is again intuitive and not too sloppy.

So what is a wise way to intuitively explain the concept of identifying one set with another?

Comment: So why -1?..... This is a good question. Are you on high, the downvoter?

Comment: For clarification, when you say "identify one set with another" you mean $A$ and $B$ are identified with one another if and only if $A=B$?  What is unsatisfying about using the actual definition in this case?  $A=B$ iff every element in $B$ must also be in $A$ and vice versa.  If this is not what you mean, then remind me what you do mean by "identifying."

Comment: @JMoravitz, Guess most present-day people would agree to use "equality" instead of "identification" in that case :). Refer to my revision.

Comment: Some people here simply go nuts if you use the word 'intuitive' in a question and will be looking to downvote as fast as they can. I wish I had a program that checked how fast something was downvoted. If it was under 30 seconds I would on principle upvote it.

Comment: One way to explain homeomorphic spaces is that by imagining the spaces as being malleable (e.g. made out of clay), the one can be transformed into the other by pushing and molding it around following a few rules such as one cannot poke new holes and one cannot close up other holes in the process (*for whatever constitutes as a hole in higher dimensions*).  See for example, the gif you can find everywhere of the coffeemug being transformed into a doughnut.  It technically misses a few cases, but not much worse than the "is continuous if drawn in one stroke" explanation

Comment: @JMoravitz, Yes, thx. I am not a native English speaker, so guess I have not yet expressed full of what I intended to say :). Topo examples are much more easier to explain, including continuity. But, for example, how could one intuitively explain that the Lebesgue spaces are strictly speaking the sets of certain equivalence classes and the usual form of a Lebesgue space is something to be identified with the corresponding set of certain equivalence classes? (I know, without symbols it is not satisfactory to describe this by words alone.).

Comment: Mathematicians tend to casually say, "we will identify A and B", where A and B are two different things, and my reaction is always, "Wait, these two things are not the same, I can't just make my brain stop knowing that these two objects are not the same object." It seems like a blatant violation of logic. I have found, though, that I can usually interpret such statements to mean "we will refer to these two different objects by the *same name*, and we will hope that it is clear from context which object we are referring to."

Comment: @littleO, Ah a nice angle

Comment: Just to clarify ... you are looking for an intuitive way to explain equinumerosity? That $|A| = |B|$?

Comment: @Bram28, yes as it seems that the problem breaks down to it majorly.

Comment: @YngwieMalmsteen OK, well, for what it's worth, I always say that "$A$ and $B$ are equinumerous if you can pair up all elements from $A$ and $B$ without any leftovers".  By 'pairing up' I avoid making any references to a function, which in my eyes introduces a kind of asymmetrical way of thinking about it, while 'pairing up' is nicely symmetrical conceptually.

Comment: @Bram28, Hum, thks for your info. It lead me thinking that it would be even better than to think of some real-life correspondence to describe the bijection thing.

Comment: @YngwieMalmsteen Yeah, sure!  The classic example is for a lecturer to ask a class of students if there are more people or chairs in the room (while the lecturer quickly goes to sit in a chair): usually there are some empty chairs left, so that means there are more chairs ... at least that works for the finite case.

Answer (score 0):

Explain to your (interested?!) friend that they already know what it means to identify two finite collections of objects - they have the same number of elements. You can match up the objects 1:1 in any manner you prefer.

Now examining 'primal' sets is fine, but what if there are relations and structures imposed on them? Then, to be identify the collections you have to preserve all those structures and relations as you match up the objects.

Example: Under a suitably defined male/female structure, there are two homeomorphism between

$\{ John, Tamara, Sally \} $

and

$\{ Patricia, Tom, Laura \} $

John $\mapsto$ Tom 
Tamara $\mapsto$ Laura 
Sally $\mapsto$ Patricia

AND

John $\mapsto$ Tom 
Tamara $\mapsto$ Patricia 
Sally $\mapsto$ Laura